# How to represent range regexp in List in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I try to implement the transformation from regexp to nfa.

Such as star regexp represents match some character zero or more times, so that it could be formulated below, the concat could match infinite lists:

```
definition star :: "'a list set ⇒ 'a list set" where
"star A = (⋃n. A ^^ n)"

lemm  "star A = {concat ws|ws. set ws ⊆ A}"
```

But for the range regexp, which could be defined as:

```
definition range ::"'a list set => nat => nat => 'a list set" where 
"range A m n = (⋃x∈(set [m..<n+1]). A ^^ x)"
```

I could figure out the solution to using the list to denote it, just like the concat operation.

Because I just want to concat N to M lists together, not the all lists.